# How would you go about optimizing(no code repetition) Java code which has many functions of this type

Tags: java, optimization, coding-style, code-cleanup

Code I inherited has many transaction code methods of this form:

```
public void addCourseToCourses(String values)
{
    try
    {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(connDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into courses values " + values);
        conn.commit();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.rollback();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(connDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(connDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Where the variable part that differs between methods is

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into courses values " + values);
```

Some times it is several inserts, sometimes it is deletes.
I Miss using Macros coming from C++, but I am sure there is a way not to repeat all this transaction code for each method.

help ?

(conn and stmt are class members of types java.sql.Connection and java.sql.Statement)

Comment: Repeat? I didn't see any repeat. Every **catch block** does a unique work. where is the repetition?

Comment: The repetition is that there are many methods like the one above each one having a different 'variable part' shown above

Comment: Apart from the problem of factoring out common tasks like logging and transaction handling, consider to use PreparedStatements instead of just Strings.

Comment: I feel compelled to point out that you are open to SQL injection there.

Comment: @Tom: thanks, but all inputs are filtered for SQLi before passing to these functions

Comment: @thedrs That's not really an adequate defence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a method that takes an interface and wraps up the exception handling.

Each interface's anonymous (or not) implementation contains the SQL call, its parameters, etc.

For example (very roughly):

```
public void addCourseToCourses(final String values) {
    handleSql(new SqlCommand() {
        @Override public void run(Statement stmt) {
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into courses values " + values);
        }
    });
}
```

The `handleSql` is a static import of something resembling:

```
public class SqlWrapper {
    public static void handleSql(SqlCommand cmd) {
        Connection conn = // get connection;
        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            return;
        }

        try {
            cmd.run();
            conn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            cleanRollback();
        } finally {
            cleanClose();
        }
    }
}
```

Various hooks can be added as seem reasonable. A generic version would allow various return types, which is likely more appropriate, just depends on what you actually need.

A comment mentions [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), IMO `Runnable` is specifically for threads (and the base interface isn't generic). `Callable` is a better choice, but I'd expect enough other hooks would be added to handle SQL-/JDBC-specific functionality that I'd use something app-specific. YMMV.

This pattern has been re-invented all over the place; it may make more sense to take something like Spring JDBC and just use that.

Comment: It's been over 15 years since I last programmed in C++, but I'm pretty sure I remember that they included methods there too.

Comment: Damn, I thought it was C# and I was writing a suggestion with a delegate. Then I realized "duh, the question is about java."

Comment: Yes, Callable<V> is better for it may turn out that one must repeat something.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't familiar with anonymous inner classes with overrides in Java. It was enlightening and constructive. Specenr Kormos's comment above was nonconstructive and of course is totally irrelevant because what I wanted to do could not be done with simple methods.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need a new interface. Existing ones like Runnable, or Callable will do just fine.

Comment: IMO it's unlikely that there would be only a single hook, rather there would be additional SQL-, JDBC-, or app-specific functionality. Maybe something extending `Callable`, but meh. `Runnable` implies a separate thread (at least to me) so I'd be wary of using it.

Comment: @Dave - Regarding Runnable, no, it doesn't. Look at it, it's just `void run();` Just because one often uses Runnable to tell a thread what to do does not mean it's its only purpose.

Comment: I didn't say it was its *only* purpose, but the Javadocs explicitly state "[...] implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread." It *is* its *canonical* purpose. I specifically said "at least to me". Like it or not, `Runnable` communicates something that may not be intended.

Comment: Well then if you insist `interface RunnableInSameThread extends Runnable {}` Regarding the above cited sentence from the javadoc, it has the same logical status as "double will be used by any class that does numeric integration". That does *not* mean you cannot use double in classes that do something else.

Comment: Again: I never claimed otherwise. You'll have to continue this one on your own, arguing about something we agree on isn't enjoyable to me.

Answer (score 1):

You use the "callback" pattern, which in java is accomplishing using anonymous classes, like this:

Create an interface to do the actual work:

```
interface Exec {
    exec(PreparedStatement stmt) throws SQLException;
}
```

Refactor your code to create method with the common code that accepts an Exec:

```
void perform(Exec exec) {
    try
    {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(connDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        exec.exec(stmt);
        conn.commit();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.rollback();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(connDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(connDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Refactor your methods like this:

```
public void addCourseToCourses(final String values)
{
    perform(new Exec() {
        exec(PreparedStatement stmt) throws SQLException {
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into courses values " + values);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: (Seems almost identical.) Is there a benefit to using a prepared statement when you're not preparing the statement?

Comment: @DaveNewton OP's question does't prepare it either (I noticed that too). I only refactored his code as-is, which answered his direct question. I didn't try to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not then just do something like this:

```
public void addCourseToCourses(String values)
{
    callDB("insert into courses values " + values)
}

protected void callDB(String call)
{
    try
    {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(connDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        stmt.executeUpdate(call);
        conn.commit();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.rollback();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(connDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(connDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This way all your transaction-related code is in one place and each individual method is only responsible for formatting the corresponding statement.

Comment: A quite bad idea. The door wide open to SQL exploits. No, use only PreparedStatements.

Comment: What if it's not an update? What if he needs `stmt.executeQuery()` or `stmt.execute()`?

Comment: This method is not good because the variable part sometimes contains more than one sql action (3 inserts and 2 deletes for example)

Comment: @Ingo: I was literally translating the code in question.  I wouldn't do it this way in my own code.

Answer (score 0):

The more amateuristic approach would be to create a method like executeSQL that handle the common stuff and you simply pass the sql (String) to execute.

A better approach would be to have a look at Spring and let Spring handle transactions and excpetion handling for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list of sql statements:

```
function void executeTransaction(List<String> sqlStatements) {
    // init transaction (as before)
    try
    {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(connDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        // execute all statements from transaction
        for(String statement: sqlStatements) {
           stmt.executeUpdate("insert into courses values " + values);
        }
        // Commit when all succeed
        conn.commit();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        try
        {
            // rollback on failure (as before)
            conn.rollback();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(connDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            // cleanup (as before)
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(connDb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```